# Xcode issue Run pre-actions

Tags: xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSZ4C.png)
exited with status code 146

This problem will occur whether it is a real machine or a simulator.

Showing All Issues

Run pre-actions

SchemeAction Run\ Script /var/folders/4v/9dbj3vr56vb2qbqdbg0l2dwc0000gn/T/SchemeScriptAction-wHjxFV.sh
cd /var/folders/4v/9dbj3vr56vb2qbqdbg0l2dwc0000gn/T/
export CA_ASSERT_MAIN_THREAD_TRANSACTIONS=1
export CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1
export COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
export DEVICE_NAME="Bryant 11 PM"
export HOME=/Users/bryanttsai
export LOGNAME=bryanttsai
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export RUN_DESTINATION_DEVICE_ECID=1218929885216814
export RUN_DESTINATION_DEVICE_MODEL=iPhone12,5
export RUN_DESTINATION_DEVICE_NAME="Bryant 11 PM"
export RUN_DESTINATION_DEVICE_OS_VERSION=17.1.1
export RUN_DESTINATION_DEVICE_PLATFORM_IDENTIFIER=com.apple.platform.iphoneos
export RUN_DESTINATION_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME=iphoneos
export RUN_DESTINATION_DEVICE_UDID=00008030-0004549C3AD0802E
export RUN_DESTINATION_DEVICE_UUID=1C3674BF-532B-47E6-AB23-63F3EFD3D7FA
export SCHEME_ACTION_NAME="Run Script"
export SCHEME_NAME=xarefit
export SHELL=/bin/zsh
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ShtaTDuc0W/Listeners
export TMPDIR=/var/folders/4v/9dbj3vr56vb2qbqdbg0l2dwc0000gn/T/
export USER=bryanttsai
export WORKSPACE_PATH=/Users/bryanttsai/hypercore/xarefit.xcworkspace
export XPC_FLAGS=0x0
export XPC_SERVICE_NAME=application.com.apple.dt.Xcode.110834215.110958344
export __CFBundleIdentifier=com.apple.dt.Xcode
export __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING="0x1F5:0x2:0x35"
/bin/sh -c /var/folders/4v/9dbj3vr56vb2qbqdbg0l2dwc0000gn/T/SchemeScriptAction-wHjxFV.sh

Invalid device type: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-12Pro

Exited with status code 146